# AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hi I am using pandas to convert a column to month. 
When I read my data they are objects:

```
Date           object
dtype: object
```

So I am first making them to date time and then try to make them as months:

```
import pandas as pd
file = '/pathtocsv.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ',', encoding='utf-8-sig', usecols= ['Date', 'ids'])    
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
```

Also if that helps:

```
In [10]: df['Date'].dtype
Out[10]: dtype('O')
```

So, the error I get is like this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _make_dt_accessor(self)
   2526             return maybe_to_datetimelike(self)
   2527         except Exception:
-> 2528             raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "
   2529                                  "values")
   2530 

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

EDITED:

Date columns are like this:

```
0         2014-01-01         
1         2014-01-01         
2         2014-01-01         
3         2014-01-01         
4         2014-01-03       
5         2014-01-03         
6         2014-01-03         
7         2014-01-07         
8         2014-01-08         
9         2014-01-09
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Your problem here is that `to_datetime` silently failed so the dtype remained as `str/object`, if you set param `errors='coerce'` then if the conversion fails for any particular string then those rows are set to `NaT`.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

So you need to find out what is wrong with those specific row values.

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: This failed for me when I stored the `pd.to_datetime()` output in an existing column with the format `str/object`. When I stored the output in a new column, it worked fine.

Answer (score 35):

First you need to define the format of date column.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

For your case base format can be set to;

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

After that you can set/change your desired output as follows;

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: It works correctly

Comment: if you have multiple timezones, convert all to utc with `, utc=True` . Otherwise you'll get: pandas Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True

Answer (score 10):

Your problem here is that the dtype of 'Date' remained as str/object. You can use the `parse_dates` parameter when using `read_csv`

```
import pandas as pd
file = '/pathtocsv.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ',', parse_dates= [col],encoding='utf-8-sig', usecols= ['Date', 'ids'],)    
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
```

From [the documentation for the `parse_dates` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> **parse_dates** : *bool or list of int or names or list of lists or dict, default False*
>
> The behavior is as follows:
>
> - boolean. If True -> try parsing the index.
> - list of int or names. e.g. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column.
> - list of lists. e.g. If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as a single date column.
> - dict, e.g. {‘foo’ : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’
>
> If a column or index cannot be represented as an array of datetimes, say because of an unparseable value or a mixture of timezones, the column or index will be returned unaltered as an object data type. For non-standard datetime parsing, use `pd.to_datetime` after `pd.read_csv`. To parse an index or column with a mixture of timezones, specify `date_parser` to be a partially-applied `pandas.to_datetime()` with `utc=True`. See Parsing a CSV with mixed timezones for more.
>
> Note: A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.

The relevant case for this question is the "list of int or names" one.

col is the columns index of 'Date' which parses as a separate date column.

Answer (score 4):

#Convert date into the proper format so that date time operation can be easily performed

```
df_Time_Table["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_Time_Table["Date"])

# Cal Year
df_Time_Table['Year'] = df_Time_Table['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y')
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer might be late, but this is what worked for my data.

Parsing timestamp to datetime object went without any errors, but I still had error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` when trying to extract minute component.
Turns out (after lengthy binary search), my data had a mixed timezone offsets, like this:

```
_time
2023-03-28T15:52:00.000-07:00
2023-02-08T11:16:13.000-08:00
```

So I added `utc=True` argument to `to_datetime` function to convert my timezone-aware timestamp strings to the UTC timestamp. Only after this exercise the error disappeared.

My full code:

```
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["_time"], errors='coerce',utc=False)
df['minute'] = df['time'].dt.minute
```

Comment: Your commentary recommends using utc=True, but the example has utc=False.

Comment: That did fix the issue indeed. Now the problem is that you might actually be interested in the timezone and the local time :-/

Answer (score 3):

`train_data=pd.read_csv("train.csv",parse_dates=["date"])`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when trying to use `pd.Series.dt.floor`, although all the elements in my `pd.Series` were `datetime.datetime` instances (absolutely no NAs). I suspect it had to do with having tz-aware instances with different timezones.

My workaround, in order to take advantage of the `pd.Timestamp.floor` method was to define the following function:

```
def floor_datetime(base_datetime_aware, freq="2H"):
    return pd.Timestamp(base_datetime_aware).floor(freq)
```

The I would just use `pd.Series.apply` to get every element of my Series through the function.

In the end, when you use the `.dt` accessor, the functions you would use are methods of the base classes, so using `apply` with a short custom function like mine may solve your problem!

Comment: How does applying floor() to the OP's `Date` column (which is of type str till converted to a datetime) solve the problem? If the solution you're proposing is to use `pd.Series.apply`, it's not better than the already [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33368021/913523) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64098826/913523) which provides the format of the data in the colum.

Comment: I got here because of I was getting the `AttributeError` mentioned in the title. What I wrote worked for my problem, and I wanted to post it in case somebody reached this post with something similar. If it's agains SO guidelines, I'd love to know.

Answer (score -1):

When you write

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d')
```

It can fixed