# How to use pandas.Series.dt.strftime can do hourly mapping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, series

Here's my data:

```
 device_create_at               
136 2014-08-27 17:29:23            
245 2015-09-06 15:46:00            
257 2014-09-29 22:26:34            
258 2014-11-05 13:02:18
```

Here's my expected output

```
  device_create_at                device_create_hour
136 2014-08-27 17:29:23            2014-08-27 17
245 2015-09-06 15:46:00            2015-09-06 15
257 2014-09-29 22:26:34            2014-09-29 22
258 2014-11-05 13:02:18            2014-11-05 13
```

As far as I know, pandas.Series.dt.strftime can do weekly mapping, the code is like this

```
sheet2['device_create_week'] = sheet2['device_create_at'].dt.strftime('%Y-%V')
```

They use `%V` for week not `%W`, I try to make this hourly

```
sheet2['device_create_hour'] = sheet2['device_create_at'].dt.strftime('%Y-%M-%D-%H')
```

That is doeesn't work

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I already update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = df.device_create_at.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
print(s)
136    2014-08-27 17
245    2015-09-06 15
257    2014-09-29 22
258    2014-11-05 13
Name: device_create_at, dtype: object
```

Note that the format is `%Y-%m-%d %H` with small `m` and small `d`.

For more info about all directives eg: %M,%m, you can find it in [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: OKm my suggestion is right. The problem on my data, error message
`Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: @NabihIbrahimBawazir The fundamental assumption with this method was that your column is a datetime column. If it's not, you'll need to use `pd.to_datetime` and convert it: `df.device_create_at = pd.to_datetime(df.device_create_at)`

Comment: yes, I already read this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365055/attributeerror-can-only-use-dt-accessor-with-datetimelike-values , and try `pd.to_datetime(df['device_create_at'], coerce=True)` and no argument call coerce

Comment: @NabihIbrahimBawazir It's `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')` in newer versions.