# Date Manipulation and Comparisons Python,Pandas and Excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a datetime column[TRANSFER_DATE] in an excel sheet shows dates formated as 
1/4/2019 0:45 when this date is selected, in it appears as 
01/04/2019 00:45:08 am using a python scrip to read this column[TRANSFER_DATE] which shows the datetime as 01/04/2019 00:45:08

However when i try to compare the column[TRANSFER_DATE] whith another date, I get this error
Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "
ValueError: : "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" while evaluating

implying those values are not actually recognized as datetime values

mask_part_date = data.loc[data['TRANSFER_DATE'].dt.date.astype(str) == '2019-04-12']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365055/attributeerror-can-only-use-dt-accessor-with-datetimelike-values), the Excel import might have silently failed for some of the values in the column. If you check the column type with:

```
data.dtypes
```

it might show as `object` instead of `datetime64`.

If you force your column to have datetime values, that might solve your issue:

```
data['TRANSFER_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TRANSFER_DATE'], errors='coerce')
```

You will spot the non-converted values as `NaT` and you can debug those manually.

Regarding your comparison, after the dataframe conversion to datetime objects, this might be more efficient:

```
mask_part_date = data.loc[data['TRANSFER_DATE'] == pd.Timestamp('2019-04-12')]
```