# What is the best practice to convert HTTP timestamps to standard format during dataframing using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, http, time-series, timestamp

I'm trying to convert HTTP timestamps into standard timestamp for complete data framing and getting time-series plots. I'm looking for an efficient way to do this for the large dataset. My actual data frame is as follows:

```
# +----------------------+-------+
# |       timestamp      |  col1 |
# +----------------------+-------+
# | 10/May/2021:19:48:36 |  714  |
# | 10/May/2021:00:28:12 |  None |
# | 10/May/2021:15:34:26 |  634  |
# | 10/May/2021:00:20:25 |  8453 |
# | 10/May/2021:14:31:32 |  None |
# +---------------------+-------+
```

I have tried couple of the following methods and get errors:

```py
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df["timestamp"]
```

This returns me `NaT` which is strange!

```
0         NaT
1         NaT
2         NaT
3         NaT
4         NaT
           ..
```

I updated the format and change it from `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` to `format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S'` and worked and I can use `df.plot(x='timestamp', y='col1')`. Additionally I don't see any changes/formatting in timestamps in plot:

[image: img]

The problem is when I plot it, timestamps related `xticks` in x axis will be plotted as they are but I couldn't limited time stamps to hours in the same day. This is not practical for my plot when events are belong to a same day. I tried to access/filter hours by this:

`df['timestamp'].dt.hour` but it returns this error: `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` I searched this error and checks previous posts in this regard but didn't work for my case like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64098826/10452700).

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: `'%d/%B/%Y:%H:%M:%S'` would be the correct parsing directive (capital B) - assuming the locale is set correctly to parse the English month names.

Comment: in general, I'd not set `errors='coerce'` at first, unless I know what to expect. Not setting the kwarg helps you find the source of the problem (here an invalid parsing directive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try via `split()`, `join()` and `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.split(':',1).str.join(' '),errors='coerce')
```

output of `df`:

```
    timestamp               col1
0   2021-05-10 19:48:36     714
1   2021-05-10 00:28:12     None
2   2021-05-10 15:34:26     634
3   2021-05-10 00:20:25     8453
4   2021-05-10 14:31:32     None
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but I still get `TypeError: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error'`

Comment: that was a typo...updated answer...Kindly check **:)**

Comment: I applied the updated answer but it seems this conversion method is not practical for 8M records!! still running...  it took 13.79 minutes !! I'm open if there is another elegant way to do this conversion but It worked and thanks for your input.